# How to convert a list of data frames into a tuple containing the data frames

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, tuples

I have a list of dataframes (df_names). I would like to convert it into the df_list. This is because I would like to create a for loop (shown at the bottom) which adds a column to each data frame and places the corresponding value/name in df_names in that column.

I've tried to remove the quotes from df_names to create df_list however, the for loop is still treating it as a list/str not as a tuple containing the data frames.

To summarise, I just want to convert the list df_names into a tuple to run the **for** loop below.

...

```
df_names = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']

df_list = [df1, df2, df3]


for i, k in zip(df_list, df_names):
    i['new_column'] = k
```

...

Comment: What is the expected output? As it stands, with your code, it adds a new column "new_column" to each dataframe where the contents of that column are the respective dataframe's names. Is this not what you want?

Comment: Can you share the dataframes?

Comment: Yes, for example df1['New_column'] would contain 'df1' for all observations. This is so I can easily tell which dataset the observation or record came from after I begin to concatenate.

Comment: It's not clear what do you want. You have a list of dataframes or only just a list of dataframes names? Are the dataframes created? or do you want to create the dataframes from the names in df_names?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I wouldn't recommend it. You should really just store your dataframes in a `dict`.

```py
df_names = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']

# Assuming df1, df2, and df3 are defined previously
df_list = [globals()[name] for name in df_names]

for i, k in zip(df_list, df_names):
    i['new_column'] = k
```

[`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) returns *the dictionary implementing the current module namespace. For code within functions, this is set when the function is defined and remains the same regardless of where the function is called.*

[`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) returns *a dictionary representing the current local symbol table. Free variables are returned by `locals()` when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks. Note that at the module level, `locals()` and `globals()` are the same dictionary.*